# How to force latex to put a quote in one line?

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv, quoting

I am currently writing a CV on LaTeX. I want to have a quote on the head of my modernCV, but latex puts ONE word into a second line. Can I make LaTeX put all the quote into one line?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\moderncvtheme[red]{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{} 
\familyname{} 
\title{\textcolor{red}{\textsc{Curriculum Vit\ae}}} 
\address{}{} 
\mobile{} 
\phone{} 
\email{} 

\quote{\glqq quote \grqq \begin{flushright} -authorname- \end{flushright}}
```

And I don't mean that the authorname is in a second line (as a matter of fact of `\flushright`) but that the quote is one word too long to fit into one line.

Comment: `flushright` is a new environment that always starts a new line.  if the author name is only one line, just use `\hfill` between the quote and the name.

Comment: The problem is, that the quote itself is split up into 2 lines. I want to have the author in a different line, that is why I put \flushright

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `TeX` code should do the trick (meant to replace `quote` in your code above):

```
\hbox to 0pt{\hss quote\hss}
```

FYI, it puts your quote in a zero-width horizontal box, with infinitely stretchable and shrinkable glue on both sides.