# LaTeX quote length / on 1 line (moderncv)

Tags: moderncv

When using the `moderncv` template in LaTeX  my quote in the heading gets split into 2 lines.
3 words are on the next line.
It looks awful so I want everything on 1 line.

I'm new to LaTeX so I can't figure it out. Here is my cv:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{lala}
\familyname{land}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{street}{lalaland}
\mobile{00000000000}
\phone{0000000000}
\email{blabla}
\extrainfo{}
\quote{"I would love to change the world, but they won't give me the source code"}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: How exactly is a question about a programming tool off-topic to this site? Kindly read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Vote to re-open.

Comment: it's not about a tool... Latex is programming 'word' in a way. And I have a question about how to program it to be on 1 line...

Comment: Depending on how long your quote is, this might also work: [How to force latex to put a quote in one line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65901/how-to-force-latex-to-put-a-quote-in-one-line)

Comment: Also note that it is much easier for people to help if you post a [`Minimal Working Example`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), being both minimal and working. I took the liberty of removing the class file you posted (it's normally part of all modern TeX distributions), removed the comments from your cv and added the missing `\end{document}`. You can still reduce its size further, but I'll leave that to you if you want to :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: > Depending on how long your quote is, this might also work: How to force latex to put a quote in one line? – Xavier yesterday thx!
worked like a charm! :)